# How to prove that the prior for which Bayes rule is also the minimax rule, is the least favorable prior?

Tags: bayesian, prior, decision-theory, extreme-value

I have read in the book Mathematical Statistics: A Decision Theoretic Approach by Thomas Ferguson that *The prior for which the Bayes rule is also minimax rule, then that prior is Least favorable prior*. Can anyone give me the proof for it? I can understand the intuition of it (I calculate Bayes and Minimax rules geometrically), but couldn't prove it.

Comment: Because of the maximin less than minimax inequality...